# Can't access a new 2008 terminal server in mixed 2003/2008 environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services

We have just set up a new 2008 terminal server.  It's joined to a domain called HOSTING and I can see the 2003 server active directory.

However, we can't seem to log onto it with users other than administrator.  Do the users have to be in a certain group to allow access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they need to be in the local Remote Desktop Users group.